# Please guide me how to add jquery in Page Viewer web part?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have added a Page viewer web part on a page. and call other SharePoint web page. I need to remove menu bar etc on this page. I got a below Jquery code from this portal.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mySiteIframe = $("#MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ2");
    mySiteIframe.load(function(){
        window.console && console.log('Loading Iframe');
        mySiteIframe.contents().find("#suiteBar").css("display", "none");
    });
});
</script>
```

but I do not know where/how this function call on page. 
Please guide me.

Comment: You need to edit the page you display in the page viewer. Otherwise jQuery that you load on the host page cannot access the page in the IFrame.

Comment: When you actually load your sharepoint page into the frame, you could also set the isDlg=1 query string parameter, and sharepoint will hide all those extras for you.